# Conditionally concatenating fields in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle12c

What I need to do is to concatenate 4 fields in Oracle SQL Developer.  The fields are:

> Network, Network2, Network3, Network4

However, sometimes not all of the fields are filled in.  This would always happen in sequence; it would never be just Network3 that's empty, it's either they fill in the first one only, the first 2 only, etc...

So, how can I write a Select statement that will ignore any fields that are NULL?  I need the end result to look like:

```
Select Network, Network2, Network3, Network4 as Defect
```

and it should show Defect as something like "ON1, ON2, ON3, ON4" all in one field.  But if only the first 2 are filled in, I don't want it to look like, "ON1, ON2, , , ".

Comment: It would be much better if your data model was normalized. Your base table shouldn't have four columns, Network, Network2 etc. Rather, it should have two columns (for these four): `Network_number` and `Value` (or `Message` or whatever the values represent). Then your query would be very easy to write with `listagg()`.

Comment: @mathguy - Agreed.  Unfortunately, this is the way our DBA designed it, and this is what I have to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`NVL2(v, valueIfNotNull, valueIfNull)`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions132.htm)

```
SELECT
    Network
 || nvl2(Network2, ', ' || Network2, '')
 || nvl2(Network3, ', ' || Network3, '')
 || nvl2(Network4, ', ' || Network4, '') AS Defect
FROM my_table
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the CONCATENATE `||` operator and `COALESCE()` function:

```
SELECT  Network
        || COALESCE(' - ' || Network2, '')
        || COALESCE(' - ' || Network3, '')
        || COALESCE(' - ' || Network4, '')
as Defect
```

Comment: Your usage of `COALESCE()` will always yield the first argument, which is never `NULL` (e.g. it would be `' - '`)

Comment: @LukasEder, wouldn't `' - '` concatenate with a potentially `NULL`-valued Network2 to produce a NULL?

Comment: I hope not :) `NULL` and the empty string are more or less the same in Oracle. You even made use of that feature by concatenating plain `Network` (which might be `NULL`) 
at the beginning of your expression!

Comment: No, I assumed that at least the first field will always have a value. I remember using NVL now. Forgot how Oracle differs from MsSQL in this case. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I see. You're right, in SQL Server `NULL` and the empty string are different things...

Comment: In the SQL standard and in valid logic (the word "logic" used in its technical sense) `null` and the empty string are very different things. Not so in Oracle. -1 to Oracle.